# State Space Representation of ODE

Tags: integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to determine a way to represent the following ODE in state space for a personal electronics project of mine.

$$
v_{c,o}+\alpha_1V_r\ (t)+\alpha_2\int_{t_0}^{\infty} V_r(t)dt+\alpha_3\frac{d}{dt}V_r\ (t)=\beta_1i(t)+\beta_2\int_{t_0}^{\infty} i(t)dt+\beta_3\frac{d}{dt}i(t)
$$

Because of the integral terms, it becomes a little trickier to set up. I don't to differentiate both sides because I lose the V_co term, which is important in my analysis. Let me know how you would approach this.

Comment: Write it as an equation in $x=\alpha_3 V_r-\beta_3 i$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not entirely sure how this would work, because it simplifies the derivative expressions and not the integral ones. Could you explain how I would use this substitution in practice?